# Logic and set theory proof help

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: 
Prove the statement below for the sets $A$,$B$, and the universal set $U$.

$$A-B=A \cap B^c $$

My attempt: 
Converting $A-B$ to set notation:
$$A-B = \left\{ {x:x \in A, x \notin B}\right\} .$$
$$A-B = \left\{ {x:x \in A \land x \notin B}\right\} .$$
$$A-B=A \cap B^c $$

Is this correct, or is my logic of the proof incorrect? 
Thanks in advanced.

EDIT:
Aaron Maroja suggested to show the converse, would that be showing: 
$$A \cap B^c = \left\{ {x:x \in A \land x \notin B}\right\}$$
$$A \cap B^c  = \left\{ {x:x \in A, x \notin B}\right\} .$$
$$A \cap B^c = A-B$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $x \in A - B \Rightarrow x \in A $ and $x \notin B$, then $x \in A \cap B^{C}$. So we  have showed that $A - B \subset A \cap B^{C}$.

Try to show the converse, that is, the other inclusion.

Comment: I think he has shown both inclusions? I mean the exercise is so trivial that you do both ways at the same time really.

Comment: Are you suggesting to also show that $A \cap B^c$ is logically equivalent to $A - B$? Basically the other way around?

Comment: To show an equality between two sets, you must conclude that $X \subset Y$ and $Y \subset X$.

Comment: Thanks, can you look at the edited post? Am I doing it right?

Comment: You're welcome. The definitions are correct. The idea behind this though, is to show that for every element $a$ in $X$, you'd have $a \in Y$ and conversely. I don't if you're are in a beginner course. If so, I suggest that you start as I said above.